# apk how to only support 1920x1080 Resolution？

Tags: android, apk

I created a apk, but I just think it only supports 1920x1080 resolution, tag(supports-screens) should be how to write? Thank you everyone!

Comment: That's going to limit your target market quite a bit.

Comment: Refer to the [Distributing to Specific Screens guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) and have a look at `requiresSmallestWidthDp` in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Please the below tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` for your `<application/>`

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false" android:smallScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="false" />
```

Comment: only for 1280x720 resolution?

Comment: Yes. Then your application supports only largescreens as `android:largeScreens="true"`

Comment: The problem is, i want to provide multiple APK upload to Google play, support 800x480(854x480,960x540), 1024x600, 1280x720(1280x768,1280x800), 1920x1080(1920x1200) four resolution, if it is the same tag filtering error

Comment: I can't understand what is the filtering error. Change the specific attributes to `true` for particular resolution.

Comment: I mean, if 1280x720's APK and 1920x1080's APK are the tag <supports-screens android:largeScreens= "true"
Android:normalScreens= "false" android:smallScreens= "false"

Android:resizeable= "true" android:anyDensity= "false" / >), when the user of the mobile phone is 1280x720, then Google play will download 1920x1080's APK, if 1920x1080's is the last upload, download the 1280x720's APK instead, right?

Comment: If this is your problem, simply place the resources in different folders - `drawable-xhdpi` for `xlarge` screens, `drawable-hdpi` for `large` screens.

Comment: Not feasible, resources are stored in the assets directory, and processed by NDK method